# Why does filling in AUCTeX behave so badly?

Tags: auctex, fill-paragraph

I'm using AUCTeX to edit LaTeX files. The behavior of the fill command <kbd>M-q</kbd> (also <kbd>C-c C-q C-p</kbd>, `LaTeX-fill-paragraph`) is very erratic. For example, if I have the following text:

```tex
test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$
```

filling it yields:

```tex
test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$
```

which is clearly not ideal. However, I have auto-fill-mode enabled, and if I take the text from the beginning and manually add a space at the end of the line, the auto-fill does this:

```tex
test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$ test $1 + 1 = 2$
test $1 + 1 = 2$
```

which is infinitely better. Is there a way I can configure the fill-command to work correctly? I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows and AUCTeX 11.88.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of filling of math switches is controlled by the [`LaTeX-fill-break-at-separators`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dfill_002dbreak_002dat_002dseparators) variable and there are currently discussions about its best default value.

I recently came up with with setting

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-fill-break-at-separators '(\\\( \\\[))
```

which fulfills the goal of keeping math formulae in the the same line (this is useful for example for `preview-latex`) and to provide a somewhat pleasing filling.  With the above setting, your code is filled as you expected (`fill-column` set to `70`).  As [suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17972/why-does-filling-in-auctex-behave-so-badly/17974?noredirect=1#comment26947_17974) by Omar Antolín-Camarena in comments,  it should be noted that the presence of the opening `\(` in that list affects also the behavior of `$` as AUCTeX treats them in the same way.

---

For the record, the above value `LaTeX-fill-break-at-separators` is now the default in the just released AUCTeX 11.89.

Comment: Sorry, I copied it wrong, you should remove the closing braces, I'm going to update the answer, i.e. use only the opening braces.  The problem of removing also the opening braces it that formulae may be broken at the end of a line, which is not good for preview-latex.

Comment: Just to be explicit for future readers: this does work even though dollar signs are not mentioned in the variable! AucTeX treats them just like `\\\(`.

Comment: The `$` seems not working here...:(

Comment: Please, provide an example.